# Reuse DNN modules in other applications

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I had an application built on top of DNN. We created a few custom DNN modules for it. Now the functionality is required in another application that is not going to be built on DNN but on plain old ASP.NET. The question is that can the existing modules somehow be reused as is in other applications as plain UserControls somehow??

Answer (score 0):

Well yes a no

If the logic and security of the module are not depedent on any of the dnn namespaces then its easy but if they are then you may have to rewrite and rethink - really though in my opnion once you have built a module its easy to rebuild it without dnn after all the real challenge is getting the logic to work that first time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you have a deep level of integration with DNN (eg exceptions, user accounts ect) you will have to swap those pieces out for whatever you will be using on the vanilla ASP.NET WebForms site.

Basically, it "can" be done but with a bit of work.